# Extracting Stock balance by comparing two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My first table is a Purchase table:

| PCODE | PCATEGORY | PNAME | PQUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1001 | CD | LIMCA | 10 |
| A1002 | JUICE | REAL | 15 |

My second table is a Sales table:

| SCODE | SCATEGORY | SNAME | SQUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1002 | JUICE | REAL | 3 |

My desired results are:

| PCODE | PCATEGORY | PNAME | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1001 | CD | LIMCA | 10 |
| A1002 | JUICE | REAL | 12 |

I have tried this code

```
SELECT PURCH.PCOD, PURCH.PCAT, PURCH.PPROD, PURCH.PQTY, SALE.SQTY
    , [PQTY]-[SQTY] AS EXP
FROM PURCH
LEFT JOIN SALE ON (PURCH.PPROD = SALE.SITM) AND (PURCH.PCAT = SALE.SCAT) AND (PURCH.PCOD = SALE.SCOD);
```

But I am getting this result - which is not what I want:

| PCODE | PCATEGORY | PNAME | PQUANTITY | SQUANTITY | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1001 | CD | LIMCA | 10 | NIL | NIL |
| A1002 | JUICE | REAL | 15 | 3 | 12 |

Can someone assist me to get my desired results please.

Comment: It looks like you just need an outer join, but perhaps consider explaining exactly what you are expecting.

Comment: I need balance stock of all items (Purchased) in query as result

Comment: If you have more than one row of a given item in either table, you might discover that you have over-simplified your schema and/or your goal.

Comment: your sample query table names/columns do not align with your sample data. You might want to look at `coalesce`?

Comment: You should ensure that the column names used in your query match the column names your provide for you sample data. You should also make the example a bit more complex (yes an unusual request I know), and show multiple Sales records. One assumes that either table could have multiple rows for the same product, and you should show this. If you were to make those changes I am confident you would get the last reopen vote required to reopen the question.

Comment: You may have an issue with your data model here. Well, maybe it's just your query, though ;-) Both tables contain a code. I assume this to be the product code. But this alone doesn't identify a product? Or why do you compare category and name in your query? Is it really possible for one code to be used for two different products of the same category? Do you really need all three columns (code, category, and name) to uniquely identify a product? What is your product table's unique key? (You do have a product table, don't you?) Wat is the sales table's key? What is the puchase table's key?

Comment: Then, please follow Dale K's advice. Explain whether there is just up to one row per product in each table or if it is possible for a product to be multiple times in a table. If the latter, what does your expected result look like then? Do you want to add up all purchases and subtract all sales per product?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a simple query with ISNULL check for the sales quantity.

**Note**:Assuming here, there is one : one mapping between purchase & sales, based on the sample data.

```sql
SELECT PURCH.PCOD, PURCH.PCAT AS PCATEGORY, PURCH.PPROD AS PNAME
    , [PQTY]- ISNULL([SQTY],0) AS QUANTITY
FROM PURCH
LEFT JOIN SALE 
ON (PURCH.PPROD = SALE.SITM) AND (PURCH.PCAT = SALE.SCAT) AND (PURCH.PCOD = SALE.SCOD);
```